# When do evaluation and the integral sign "commute"?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, functions

This is a difficult question to put into words so it's much easier to write the math.

Let $a$ and $b$ be given constants and $g(y) \equiv \int_a^b f(x,y) dx$.

When is $g(c) = \int_a^b f(x,c) dx$?

I know this would be a blunder if the integration and evaluation variables were the same so please do not mistake that case for this.
What about the converse?

$\int_a^b f(x,c) dx = g(c)$

I'm asking these two questions for general $f(x,y)$ but smooth functions in $x$ and $y$ are my most important concern.

EDIT: Reworded question significantly to be more precise about what I mean. I was originally using the notation:

$\left[\int_a^b f(x,y)dx\right]_{y=c} = \int_a^b [f(x,y)]_{y=c}dx = \int_a^b f(x,c)dy$

Comment: There is no problem at all. You are given a function $f$ on some rectangle $[a,b]\times[p,q]$ and are considering the integral of $f$ along segments $y=c\in[p,q]$. The value of this integral is a function of the chosen "level" $c$ and can therefore be denoted by $g(c)$.

Comment: The subtlety is whether $g$ itself is a continuous, differentiable, smooth etc. function.

Answer (score 0):

Those things are equal by definition of $\int_a^b f(x,y) dx$. If $g(y)=\int_a^b f(x,y) dx$, then $g(c)$ means $\int_a^b f(x,c) dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on what *you* mean by these expressions but if we assume $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function of both variables and by $\int_a^b f(x,y)dx$ you mean the function $y \mapsto g(y) = \int_a^b f(x,y)dx$, then of course 
$$
g(c) = \left[\int_a^b f(x,y)dx\right]_{y=c} = \int_a^b [f(x,y)]_{y=c}dx = \int_a^b f(x,c)dy
$$
by definition.